# Extracting numbers from character string based on delimiters

Tags: r, regex, substr

I have the following dataframe:

```
a <- seq(1:5)
b <- c("abc_a_123456_defghij_1", "abc_a_78912_abc_2", "abc_a_345678912_xyzabc_3",
                          "abc_b_34567_defgh_4", "abc_c_891234556778_ijklmnop_5")
df <- data.frame(a, b)
df$b <- as.character(df$b)
```

And I need to extract the numbers in df$b that come between the second and third underscores and assign to df$c.

I'm guessing there's a fairly simple solution, but haven't found it yet. The actual dataset is fairly large (3MM rows) so efficiency is a bit of a factor.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you giving us `a`?  It seems only `b` is necessary to solve this, no?

Comment: You're right, a is unnecessary, sorry about that

Comment: Seems like `sub(".*_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", b)` might work.

Comment: @DarshanBaral - It is quite general, searching for the first section of the string that contains `_`, then digit(s), then another `_`. And then it keeps just the the digits. See `help(regex)`

Comment: @RichScriven - Thanks! What does  `"\\1"` specify? My actual dataset has a few more parts to the string, and this is extracting the second to last part.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` to match the zeor or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by an underscore (`_`), then another set of characters that are not an underscore followed by underscore, capture the one of more numbers that follows in a group (`(\\d+)`) followed by underscore and other characters, then replace it with the backreference for that group and finally convert it to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(sub("^[^_]*_[^_]+_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", df$b))
#[1]       123456        78912    345678912        34567 891234556778
```

Answer (score 1):

create a `my_split` function that finds the start and end position of "_" using `gregexpr`. Then extract the string between start and end position using `substr`.

```
my_split <- function(x, start, end){
  a1 <- gregexpr("_", x)
  substr(x, a1[[1]][start]+1, a1[[1]][end]-1)
}

b <- c("abc_a_123456_defghij_1", "abc_a_78912_abc_2", "abc_a_345678912_xyzabc_3", "abc_b_34567_defgh_4", "abc_c_891234556778_ijklmnop_5")

sapply(b, my_split, start = 2, end = 3)
# abc_a_123456_defghij_1             abc_a_78912_abc_2 
# "123456"                       "78912" 
# abc_a_345678912_xyzabc_3           abc_b_34567_defgh_4 
# "345678912"                       "34567" 
# abc_c_891234556778_ijklmnop_5 
# "891234556778"
```

using data.table library

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c := lapply(b, my_split, start = 2, end = 3)]
df
#    a                             b            c
# 1: 1        abc_a_123456_defghij_1       123456
# 2: 2             abc_a_78912_abc_2        78912
# 3: 3      abc_a_345678912_xyzabc_3    345678912
# 4: 4           abc_b_34567_defgh_4        34567
# 5: 5 abc_c_891234556778_ijklmnop_5 891234556778
```

data:

```
a <- seq(1:5)
b <- c("abc_a_123456_defghij_1", "abc_a_78912_abc_2", "abc_a_345678912_xyzabc_3", "abc_b_34567_defgh_4", "abc_c_891234556778_ijklmnop_5")
df <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: you can play around with start and end values