# Extract values in a column using R

Tags: r, regex

I have a column having values as shown in below.

```
v2 <- c("[0,1]", "[4,8]", "[10, 23]")
df <- data.frame(v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How could I extract the first number (lower bound) and the second number (upper bound)? and saved into column Min and Max?

Thanks!

-Shelly

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, people getting a little carried away with that I think. +1 just to undo it.

Comment: You should start with function that splits range in two values, once you have it you can use one of ‘apply’ functions over your vector to generate matrix of results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting numbers from character string based on delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641890/extracting-numbers-from-character-string-based-on-delimiters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strcapture` to capture the values, and also ensure the dataframe takes in `numeric values`

```
strcapture("(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)",v2,data.frame(Min=numeric(),Max=numeric()))
  Min Max
1   0   1
2   4   8
3  10  23
```

or you can do

```
read.csv(text=gsub("\\[|\\]","",v2),h=F,col.names = c("Min","Max"))
  Min Max
1   0   1
2   4   8
3  10  23
```

or you can use `extract` from tidyr:

```
tidyr::extract(df, v2,c("Min","Max"),"(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)")
  Min Max
1   0   1
2   4   8
3  10  23
```